# why do i have to open a file in binary mode to write in it in c?

Tags: c, fopen

```
fprintf(file, "%d %d %d", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
```

for this statement to work i have to open the file in 'wb' mode rather than 'w' mode . How does a binary mode make the syntax work?

Comment: You don't have to open it in binary mode. Are you calling fflush() or fclose() to flush the output.

Comment: how are you trying to open and read the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get a file pointer using fopen
FILE *fp = fopen("file.bin", "r+");
Then use fread to read and fwrite to .. write. See [this](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fread/)
Also please do read the manual carefully and note fread and fwrite return an integer which *should* be checked to see exactly how much has been read/written.

Comment: But the "amount written" can and will be wrong on Windows unless you use binary mode. Basically you should always use binary mode.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using this function when opening the file:

```
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
```

When you are programming under Linux `b` is ignored, as it doesn't have any effect. From **[man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)**:

> The  mode string can also include the
>   letter 'b' either as a last char‐
>          acter or as a character between the characters in any of the 
>   two-char‐
>          acter strings described above.  This is strictly for compatibility
>   with
>          C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all POSIX conforming 
>   sys‐
>          tems,  including Linux.  (Other systems may treat text files and
>   binary
>          files differently, and adding the 'b' may be a good idea if you do 
>   I/O
>          to a binary file and expect that your program may be ported to
>   non-Unix
>          environments.)

As for Windows (source **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859631.aspx)**):

> b : Open in binary (untranslated)
>   mode; translations involving
>   carriage-return and linefeed
>   characters are suppressed.

So the conclusion: 
If you want portable access to binary data in C code, for compatibility reasons use 'b'.

Comment: "If you want portable C code, for compatibility reasons use 'b'" is misleading and/or wrong for those writing text files.  Your conclusion is only true for binary files or for people who believe that non-CRLF text files are "good enough for most purposes" on Windows and that no other weird-line-endings platforms exist.

Comment: @John: Generating portable data files is a lot more important (to most people) than conforming to perverse line-ending characteristics of oddball platforms. Even if my code were running on a system that had "text files" with fixed-record-size lines or a 5-byte sequence of `\r\r\r\r\n` for line breaks, I would want to work with files suitable for interchange with the real world and ignore the system-local notion of "text files" entirely.

Comment: @R..: well, duh, yes of course there are advantages to such a lazy approach.  There are also advantages to being able to look at your textual data files in a text editor on your local system.  (And I would suggest that "If you want portable C code, use 'b'" -- **code**, not the resulting files -- remains a massive oversummary.)