# Unsupported file after duplicating it

Tags: c, windows, file

I wrote a VERY simple program that copies all the bytes from a selected file and write them in a new/selected file.
What I want to do is duplicate 'elaborate' (encoded) file such `.jpg`, `.png`, `.mp3`, `.exe` and so on...
The program works fine (especially using simple .txt file), here is a running example:

*(Wrote and compiled in windows using mingw)*:

```
C:\Users\Computer\Desktop>duplicate.exe img.jpg file.txt
```

*Content of file.txt*:

```
ÿØÿà JFIF      ÿÛ C
```

If `file.txt` would have been substituted with `<filename>.<new_file_extention>`, the program would have create the new file and copied the above content inside as in:

```
C:\Users\Computer\Desktop>duplicate.exe img.jpg new_img.jpg
```

When I try to open `new_img.jpg` though the OS says me that the file is not supported hence cannot be opened.

***My reasoning before writing the program was the following: "At bottom level any file is just a sequence of bytes, hence copying from an existing file and pasting onto a brand new/selected file will result in actually duplicating the file avoiding any type of encoding."***

Here is the code:

```
//The program is just a test, is not a final version, hence the absence of some error handling. 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXBYTE     2500
#define RDWRMAX     1024

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int ifd, ofd, n;
    char buf[MAXBYTE+1];

    if((ifd = open(*++argv, O_RDONLY, 0)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open '%s'.\n", *argv);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if((ofd = open(*++argv, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open '%s'.\n", *argv);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((n = read(ifd, buf, RDWRMAX)) > 0)
        write(ofd, buf, n);
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and maybe suggesting some possible way to solve it? This is a learning process for me, so thanks in advance for all the useful answers to this question.

Comment: Based on the fact that the paths exhibited seem suspiciously "Windows"-ish, I'm curious what happens when you bit-or `_O_BINARY` to your open mode options.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks a lot. Now it works. I am sorry I am not able to upvote your comment. Just because I am curious, why does this works? I search on the internet and found no documentation talking about O_BINARY open mode, only problems relative to that.

Comment: In windows when opening a file in “text mode” that file undergoes a translation. This changes around what certain characters are and adds some as well. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703872/why-do-i-have-to-open-a-file-in-binary-mode-to-write-in-it-in-c) for more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between files written in binary and text mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229924/difference-between-files-written-in-binary-and-text-mode)